# How can I fix a container at the bottom of the screen on scroll and make sure that container is fluid?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that is fixed to the bottom of the screen.

I would like the container "black-bg" to expand and contract (fluid) based off of the paragraph content inside of it. The div "graphic"  right above it should also move relatively to "black-bg" div and not be fixed

Currently "black-bg" and "graphic" and is fixed in the same place and does not move no matter if the paragraph content changes or not.

**Also I would like the container "black-bg" div bottom aligned not top aligned within "my-container" div so that it sits right on top "options" div**

My code is below:

```css
.my-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.37rem;
  padding: 13px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
  /* opacity: 0.1; */
  min-height: 222px;
  max-height: 752px;
}

.black-bg {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 27px 23px 67px 90px;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -19px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.options {
  background-color: #b1151b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.37rem;
  padding: 0 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 30;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.options a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.options>a.left-btn {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 85px;
}

.options>a.left-btn,
.options>a.right-btn {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <div class="graphic">
    <div>Graphic will go here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="black-bg">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    <h4>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <a href="#" class="left-btn">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" class="right-btn">No</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have added the fiddle to your question but there is something very very wrong with your code

Comment: @DigitalJedi Thanks. Where is the fiddle?

Comment: sry mb i meant snippet ;) - but as I said - the code is very wrong - so it doesnt show anything

Comment: @DigitalJedi I see. I had it on display none for some reason.

Comment: I got it to show in snippet but not in codepen.

Comment: whatever changes you made to it also have it looking responsive in codepen. https://codepen.io/Griehle/pen/yWmyVV

Comment: @Griehle I would like the container black-bg bottom aligned, not top aligned within .my-container div so that it sits right on top "options" div

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite know if this is what you want, but I think the problem you have is that you have applied `position: fixed` to your outermost container, so your whole content is fixed.

I think only want to fix the footer, and not everything like this:

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container{
  color: white;
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.37rem;
  padding: 13px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* opacity: 0.1; */
  min-height: 222px;
  max-height: 752px;
  }

.black-bg {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 27px 23px 67px 90px;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -19px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.options {
  background-color: #b1151b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.37rem;
  padding: 0 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 30;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.options a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.options>a.left-btn {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 85px;
}

.options>a.left-btn,
.options>a.right-btn {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="graphic">
    <div>Graphic will go here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="black-bg">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam

</p>
    <h4>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</h4>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="options">
    <a href="#" class="left-btn">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" class="right-btn">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fine but I would like the container black-bg bottom aligned, not top aligned within .my-container div so that it sits right on top "options" div